# Two-Way MultiBinding single property in ViewModel to multiple properties in View - can I revert IMultiValueConverter?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I want to map a single property in my ViewModel to multiple properties in my View using an `IMultiValueConverter`, but I noticed the `Convert` maps many-to one, `ConvertBack` method maps one to many.

The problem is I need this to be reversed, that is, I want have multiple properties in the View to depend upon a single property in ViewModel, and for that the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` signatures (or calls) should be exchanged.

Is there a way for the MultiBinding to call `ConvertBack` method in place of `Convert`, and vice-versa?

Comment: There only is a way to reverse the `IMultiValueConverter` if the underlying function of convert has an inverse. It's math.

Comment: @H.B. I edited the question. What I meant is that I would need `Convert` method to be called instead of `ConvertBack` and vice-versa, since the MultiBinding is a one-to-many transformation, but usually it generates one value to the view from multiple values in ViewModel, and I need the opposite: many properties in the view mapping to a single property in ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for a normal converter, where you just single out your required value and read/write that.

Alternatively write convenience properties and bind to those instead.

Comment: I was thinking about it already... Gonna give it a try and perhaps wait for more answers, but I think this is a quite sound approach, thanks for now!

Comment: I have failed to make it two-way. When I change one of the properties in View, the bound object does not update. So, say I have an `Interval` property with `Start` and `End` properties, when I change `End` property (using a slider), I don't get a new `Interval` instance at the ViewModel.

Comment: Well, is the `Interval` a struct? That would require you to assign a new instance.

Comment: Yeah, it's sort of a struct (its only "state" is in its property values), so it could be replaced, but it doesn't implement INPC, so the slider actually changes the property value at the source, but instead I would need to generate a new instance, with the new value, at the target (view), and send it back to ViewModel.

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example that illustrates the problem and explain what the outcome is and what the desired result should be? It's a bit hard to image the complete scenario.

Comment: I want viewModel withproperty `Interval(start=0.33, end=0.66)` and each property linked to a different slider, then when I move the end slider, say, from 0.66 to 0.77, the Interval property in ViewModel now has Start=0.33 and End = 0.77.

Comment: So is it a struct or a class? "Sort of a struct" is not a thing.

Comment: It _is_ a class, currently. If the design would call for a struct, there would be no problem for me to change it to a struct, that's what I meant - it _could_ be a struct.

Comment: Then changes to the properties should change the correct instance of the view model, if anything the view does not change because your sub-properties lack change notifications.